# Web deployment of document containing URLSave function

Tags: deployment, web-access

Is it possible to deploy a *Mathematica* notebook which contains a dynamic `URLSave` function? My code has the following structure:

```
web = URLSave["http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/", Close[OpenTemporary[]]]
web = Import[web, {"GZIP", "Text"}]
Dynamic[web, UpdateInterval -> 20, TrackedSymbols -> {}, SynchronousUpdating -> False]
```

The problem is when I start to deploy it, in the last step after I indicate in which folder to save the CDF file, then this error appears:

> Select::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in Select[C:\Users\Morry\Dropbox\MEPS\ALISalehi\HTML\146\Untitled.cdf,StringMatchQ[#1,*.png]&].

Answer (score 4):

Due to security reasons it is impossible to write to the filesystem from a web-embedded CDF.

Comment: What about WebMathematica?